# Implementing vertical movement controlls

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, three.js

```
if ( upDownMovement == true) {  
                        SELECTED.position.y = mouse.y * scale;
                              }
```

This is my naive way of implementing a vertical movement control ( as in directly up and down in the Y only). There is a critical problem with it, however. Because initial mouse position is discontinuous with the models original position, there is always a "jump" at the beginning of the movement.

What is the proper way to implement this control? (If there is a library that does this well, I would love to see it.)

I am thinking something like SELECTED.position.y = SELECTED.position.y + mouse.y * scale; but I could vary well be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you should get the initial mouse position (when `upDownMovement` become true) and use it as a reference. Something like

```
if (upDownMovement == true) {
  mouse_y_reference = mouse_y_reference || mouse.y;
  SELECTED.position.y += (mouse.y - mouse_y_reference) * scale;
} else {
  mouse_y_reference = null;
}
```

If you want something smoother, you may use an animation library such as [tween.js](https://github.com/sole/tween.js), to do something like

```
mouse_y_reference = mouse_y_reference || mouse.y; // must be declared in a higher scope
var toY = SELECTED.position.y + (mouse.y - mouse_y_reference) * scale;
new TWEEN.Tween(SELECTED.position)
  .to({ y: toY }, 100) // adjust the duration here
  .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Elastic.InOut )
  .onComplete(function() {
    mouse_y_reference = null;
  })
  .start();
```